# Determine multivariable function is differentiable or not

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

Hi guys I have exercise on differentiability of multivariable function.I have found the partial derivatives of x and y but I do not know how to go further. 
Let $f(x,y)=xy+\frac{1}{xy}$ .
 Show that the function f is differentiable at point (5,6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have computed the partial derivatives, you are basically done. They are continuous, right?! So, $f$ is differentiable.

Or you can say that the functions $(x,y)\mapsto x$ and $(x,y)\mapsto y$ are differentiable, which implies that $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ is differentiable, which implies that $(x,y)\mapsto\frac1{xy}$ is differentiable. Since your function is the sum of two differentiable functions, it is differentiable.

Comment: I have found $fx=y-\frac{1}{x^2y}$ and  $fy=x-\frac{1}{xy^2}$ How can I know they are continuous?

Comment: They are obtained from continuous functions using arithmetic operations. Isn't that enough?

Comment: Thanks I got it